# postfix for magento

Tags: magento2, email, smtp

I use postfix to handle emails for magento (new order email/invoice email etc). what I do is setup a relay SMTP which in turn use my gmail account.

```
smtp server : smtp.gmail.com
port: 587
account: myAccout@gmail.com
```

this function is working and emails are sending out as expected. but I found the **From** value is **myAccout@gmail.com** , which I expect it to be **customerSupport@myDomain.tld** as I specified in magento admin.

Question 1: Is there way I can make postfix to show address I set in magento admin as email's **FROM** value ?

Question 2: To relay a gmail (or outlook) account, it may have limitation on how many emails you are allowed to send out one day (for example 500). Therefore, Is a relay SMTP a common practice to handle email. currently I use the **Exchange Online** to host my email. Can I leverage it to send email?

any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When using gmail as the SMTP relay, Google automatically replaces the "FROM" and the "REPLY-TO" headers for outgoing mail to be the address you're relaying through.  This is most likely to prevent gmail IP addresses being marked as spam (or individual accounts marked as spam accounts).

More info: https://serverfault.com/questions/152604/smtp-relay-through-gmail-overrides-from-address-with-megmail-com

See this ServerFault post: https://serverfault.com/questions/249636/postfix-relays-via-gmail-from-email-is-wrong

*EDIT:* If you host your website on AWS, SMTP Relay is the only way to send email.  In AWS's instance you use the Simple Email Service which you whitelist sending addresses individually and the email is sent just fine.

I'm not sure how other services act as I've only used AWS SES for emails.  The resource limits for AWS SES are pretty good, unless you're sending out thousands of emails per minute.  There are other services like MailGun and SendGrid which provide the same service as AWS SES but are hosted by other agencies (Rackspace is one).  Never really used those, so YMMV.

*Note:* With Magento Enterprise Cloud, this is most likely how emails will be sent out.

Comment: thanks Brett. Actually i found I don't have to relay on any existing account like gmail or outlook etc. and it's just working out of the box except a few config (TLS, encrypt etc) in the main.cf of postfix. That's to say after remove the relay part, the "From" value is correct.

Comment: But now, i am struggling with another issue. if I set newOrder@myDomain.tld as the new order sender address, email can successfully be sent to gmail recipient. But if receiver email is an outlook address, email is rejected and bounced. As i said, i used online exchange product (smart host) from microsoft, i have the SPF records (TXT record) `v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`. By googling, i change it to `v=spf1 ip4:<My server IP Address> include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all`. But still have no luck. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm not an authority on SPF records, but it may be that you need to add an "a" mechanism specifying the domain(s) you will be sending from.  Also, according to the openspf.org some domains will keep banning you based on a PermError from a previously invalid SPF record.

http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax